# Django Static Files on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, django-staticfiles

I copied google cloud sample Django project for google appengine. Then, I modified settings.py for storing all static files on google storage. I added this settings

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gs.GSBotoStorage'
GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'YourID'
GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'YourKEY'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'YourBucket'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gs.GSBotoStorage'
```

On local machine everything is working perfectly but when I deploy it to google appengine static file problem appears. Django can't find static files which in special google storage bucket. This is the error message:

> ImportError at /admin/login/ cannot import name SpooledTemporaryFile

in app.yaml file, settings about static files:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: .*
  script: mysite.wsgi.application
```

I am new at google cloud and i can't figure it out where I am doing wrong.

Edit: I think, I must modify app.yaml file to say appengine "Hey, use another bucket don't serve static file yourself".

Tere is more detailed error output:

> ImportError at /admin/ cannot import name SpooledTemporaryFile Request
>   Method: GET Request URL: https://sbminteractive.appspot.com/admin/
>   Django Version:
>   1.8 Exception Type: ImportError Exception Value: cannot import name SpooledTemporaryFile Exception Location:
>   /base/data/home/apps/e~sbminteractive/20170414t175601.400554512166425273/lib/storages/backends/s3boto.py
>   in , line 6 Python Executable:
>   /base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/python Python Version:
>   2.7.5 Python Path: ['/base/data/home/apps/e~sbminteractive/20170414t175601.400554512166425273',
>   '/base/data/home/apps/e~sbminteractive/20170414t175601.400554512166425273/lib',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python27.zip', 
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7', 
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1', 
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.5',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10']
>   Server time: Fri, 14 Apr 2017 14:57:51 +0000

Comment: google docs has prepared for professionals. You can try heroku or amazon AWS. You can find tons of video or documentation. Do not waste your time with google.

Comment: Check this doc:
https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment

Open mysite/settings.py for editing.

Set the value of STATIC_URL to the following URL. Replace <your-gcs-bucket> with the bucket name you created earlier.